# Get an error while run react-native project that i just created

Tags: react-native

[image]

I just created a new react native project and run it, but it shows error like this.

Suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the error with the following in .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/saif-ams/MyFiles/applications/androidsdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```